# React Native- How can I call a function of a child view from its parent?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am new on react native and came accross this problem. I have a tab view with 2 tabs in tabview.js file and tab1.js and tab2.js for tab1 and tab2.
So when the page loads the both tabs componentDidMount function calls loadData function which fetches data from web. Now I want to refresh the data when I change tabs. But how can I call the loadData function of tab1.js inside tabview.js?

Here are codes I am using

tabview.js

```
render() {
 return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <Header style={{flex: 1}} />
  <ScrollableTabView style={{flex: 10}} onChangeTab={(e)=>{this.checkTabPosition(e)}}>
    <Tab1 tabLabel="Tab1" navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
    <Tab2 tabLabel="Tab2" navigator={this.props.navigator} />
  </ScrollableTabView>
  </View>
 );
}
```

tab1.js

```
render() {
    return (
        <ScrollView refreshControl={
                    <RefreshControl
                        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
                        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
                    />
                }
                >
        <View>
            <ListView style={styles.listview}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={(rowData) => <ListItem rowData={rowData} navigator={this.props.navigator} />}
                enableEmptySections={true}
            />
        </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.fetchData();
}
```

Same in tab2.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a `ref` to your Tabs and then use `this.refs`. Your code will look like this:

```
checkTabPosition(e){
    // determine which tab to refresh
    var tabToRefresh = ...;

    // refresh tab
    refreshTab(tabToRefresh);
}

refreshTab( tab ){
  this.refs[tab].fetchData();
}

render() {
 return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
       <Header style={{flex: 1}} />
       <ScrollableTabView style={{flex: 10}} onChangeTab={(e)=>    {this.checkTabPosition(e)}}>
          <Tab1 ref="tab1" tabLabel="Tab1" navigator={this.props.navigator}/>
          <Tab2 ref="tab2" tabLabel="Tab2" navigator={this.props.navigator} />
       </ScrollableTabView>
    </View>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the `props` hell problem ;). That is why in React, it is recommended to have your state as high up the hierarchy as possible, or use some state management library: (Flux, Redux, etc).

In your case, you should move the tabs data to your parent component `TabView`. Then you can do:

```
<Tab1 data={this.state.yourTab1Data} ... />
<Tab2 data={this.state.yourTab2Data} ... />
```

Finally, your `onChangeTab` should invoke your refresh process (probably fetching data), when that data is fetched, you will use `setState` in your `TabView` component and the re-render will cause that `data` prop to be passed to `Tab1` and `Tab2` so you will have what you were looking for.

Basically you need to work from top to the bottom. And since passing callbacks is painful, that is why you might want to use a state management library which of course, it is totally optional.

Comment: Yes I am going to use Redux.